# google-authenticator codes not working while emergency scratch codes do it right

Tags: ssh, debian, security, google-authenticator

Installing google-authenticator on a Debian behind another Debian firewall in a very restricted configuration on connectivity 
(NetinVM, a virtual machine constellation inside a VM)

Installation goes OK
Synchronisation with phone app OK
SSH connection ask for codes OK
but phone generated codes do NOT work
tried with Emergency scratch codes, it goes OK

I analyse traffic on server (machine with ssh and g-auth), client, and firewall machine, no one of them shows sings of any intentions of connection to google servers. But I presume it should exist, isn't it ?

Any help on this matter ?

Package:
apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator

Not sure if useful, but. As creating the synchronisation with mobile, doesn't matter if doing with the QR or entering manually the long secret key, the verification code is never asked/used.

Sample:

```
Your new secret key is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP 
Your verification code is 123456 
Your emergency scratch codes are: 
12345678 
90123456 
78901234 
56789012 
34567890
```

Comment: Check your clocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Authenticator is time-dependent. Make sure your date/time settings, from the server and the phone, (also including their timezones) are correct.

Comment: Indeed!!  I didn't expect that will be the matter, it would be good that is advised in the setup. THANKS !!

Comment: on the other hand, it seems, that all the codes are "pre-programed" ?? there is no more entropy than the algorithm that generates the codes based on a secret key of 26 characters  >> crying a lot  :__((